# Python - Count how many elements from a list appear in a csv line

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I have a large list of many strings such as ':0001959' etc... I also have a file with many csv lines and some of these lines contain the strings I have in this list. What I need to do, is to count (for each line) how many elements from this list are matched to each line.

```
 split_string = line.split(",")
         for split_string in line:
             if split_string[0] in Lethality:
                  count = count +1
```

The above code is a quick look at what I already have.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through the elements in the `split_string` list which contains your csv splitted data, you are going to override `split_string` with the characters that are in the original csv line with this for loop, so you can modify your code as :

```
split_string = line.split(",")
for element in split_string:
    if element in Lethality:
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: That is the second time I made this mistake. Thank you.